# js code making wrong rotation on image on start

Tags: javascript, mobile

I'm using a code that helps me to move, resize and rotate images on my website.

I already had a problem with it on mobile where the rotation was reverse and managed to correct it but now i have another problem that i'm stuck with.

When my website is loading the images for the first time with their position, rotation etc... the images on pc with a rotation of +n degres become -n degres and the opposite append on mobile.

here is the code :

```
e[a].Layer.prototype.rotateTo = function(e, a) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
        var r = this, s = this.rotation;
        0 != r.index && (e *= 1, t([r.cont[0], r.handler[0]]).css({
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            transform: "rotate(" + e + "deg)"
        }), e = e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : 360 - e, r.changeResizeCorner(2 * Math.round(e / 90)), r.rotation = e, a || r.$this.change(s !== r.rotation ? ["rotation"] : i))
    } else { 
        var r = this, s = this.rotation;
        0 != r.index && (e *= -1, t([r.cont[0], r.handler[0]]).css({
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            transform: "rotate(" + e + "deg)"
        }), e = e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : 360 - e, r.changeResizeCorner(2 * Math.round(e / 90)), r.rotation = e, a || r.$this.change(s !== r.rotation ? ["rotation"] : i))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the e *= line.

```
e[a].Layer.prototype.rotateTo = function(e, a) {
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)) {
        var r = this, s = this.rotation;
        0 != r.index && (e *= 1, t([r.cont[0], r.handler[0]]).css({
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            transform: "rotate(" + e + "deg)"
        }), e = e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : 360 - e, r.changeResizeCorner(2 * Math.round(e / 90)), r.rotation = e, a || r.$this.change(s !== r.rotation ? ["rotation"] : i))
    } else { 
        var r = this, s = this.rotation;
        0 != r.index && (e *= 1, t([r.cont[0], r.handler[0]]).css({
            "-moz-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-o-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            "-webkit-transform": "rotate(" + e + "deg)",
            transform: "rotate(" + e + "deg)"
        }), e = e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : 360 - e, r.changeResizeCorner(2 * Math.round(e / 90)), r.rotation = e, a || r.$this.change(s !== r.rotation ? ["rotation"] : i))
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried but if i do that the rotation works fine the first time it's loaded, but rotate in a reverse sens when i try to turn it myself (on pc)

Comment: It seems that "e = e < 0 ? Math.abs(e) : 360 - e" part results "360 - e" and might turn it counter clockwise. Instead of that could you just use "Math.abs(e)"